# Defining a test function $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ on Matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution-theory, piecewise-continuity

So the following, $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$, is an archetypal test function on $\mathbb{R}$:

$$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\right),&\mbox{if }|x|<1,
\\
0,&\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
I am having difficulty defining it, let alone plotting it on Matlab though. I used:

`function y=test(x)
    y1=(exp(1/(1-x^2))).*abs(x)<1;
    y2=(0).*abs(x)>=1;
    y=y1+y2;
end`

Then attempted to plot with

`x = -2:0.01:2;
y=test(x);
plot(x,y)`

Only to receive the error message:

`Error in test (line 2)
    y1=(exp(1/(1-x^2))).*abs(x)<1;`

However, I cannot spot the problem and Matlab seems to indicate that my function definition is fine otherwise.

Comment: I don't think it works with the distinction between these cases how you have done it. MATLAB doesn't like boolean arguments in this way. I'd implement it with something like this:

`if abs(x)<1 
     y1=...;
 else 
     y2=...;`

Comment: @MarvinF. I did `function y=test(x)
    if abs(x)<1
        y=exp(1/(1-x^2));
    else
        y=0;
    end`
and then `x = -2:0.01:2;
y=test(x);
plot(x,y)` returned an empty plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define `x = -2:0.01:2`. And now let's use the pre-defined Heaviside-function

[image: Heaviside]

to define a step function that is one between $-1$ and $1$; and zero otherwise. This is given by:

`s = heaviside(x+1).*heaviside(-x)+heaviside(x).*heaviside(1-x)`

[image: Step]

From here on we just need to multiply your $\phi$ by this step function $s$ to get the wanted result. So we avoid this distinction case pretty elegantly.

`phi=(exp(-1./(1-x.^2))).*s`

And plotting this gives via `plot(x,phi)`

[image: test function]

as we wanted.

---

Integration can be done as follows:

`s = @(x)heaviside(x+1).*heaviside(-x)+heaviside(x).*heaviside(1-x);
phi = @(x) exp(-1./(1-x.^2)).*s(x);
d = @(t) integral(@(x)phi(x),0,t);
fplot(d,[0,1])`

Getting the following plot:

[image: integral]

It can be seen quiet nicely that for increasing $t$ the integral in not increasing as much as in the beginning.

Comment: That certainly gives me the plot, although it doesn't leave me with room to do much else; for example: integration of $\phi$.

Comment: @user3482534 Just define $\phi$ with a function handle so you can integrate it like this https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html. That means you define `s = @(x)  heaviside(x+1)*heaviside(-x)+heaviside(x)*heaviside(1-x)` and `phi = @(x) exp(-1/(1-x^2))*s(x)`. To plot a function handle use `fplot`.

Comment: @user3482534 Notice that $$s(x)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\right)=\begin{cases}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\right),&\mbox{if }|x|<1
\\
0,&\mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$  where $s(x)=\begin{cases} 1, ~|x|<1 \\ 0, ~\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Comment: I guess this is kind of "off-topic", but would you be able to give any pointers why this integration plot is not working? `t=0:0.01:4;
s = @(x) heaviside(x+1)*heaviside(-x)+heaviside(x)*heaviside(1-x);
phi = @(x) exp(-1/(1-x.^2))*s(x);
d = @(t) integral(phi,0,t);
plot(t,d)`

Comment: @user3482534 You can either pre-define `t` or you can use a function handle with `@(t)` but MATLAB doesn't like it if you use both. In you case you should use `fplot(d,[0,4])` to plot the function handle `d` for $t \in [0,4]$. I add something in the post, one moment.